# in pandas, calculate product of row values in a column (which are grouped by a category) and assign the product value to all rows in each group?

Tags: python, pandas

my dataframe df has 3 columns 
'part': part number
'test': test name
'test_pass': pass or fail result for each test.1 is pass, 0 is fail.

[image]

i want to create a fourth column 'part_pass'. 
For any 'part' if there is at least one 'test_pass' equal to 0, that 'part' is a failing part. For that part i want to get 'part_pass' equal to 0 for all rows for that 'part'.

For any 'part' if all the 'test_pass' equal to 1, that 'part' is a passing part. For that part i want to get 'part_pass' equal to 1 for all rows for that 'part'.

[image]

How do i calculate the product of 'test_pass' grouped by 'part' and assign the resulting value to the rows of 'part_pass' by part group?

Comment: Don't post images. Post a code to easily reproduce your data set instead

Comment: Sorry, this was my first ever attempt to ask a question on Stackoverflow. Next time, I will make sure to include code, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to reproduce your data set:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["part"] = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
df["test"] = ["test1"]*3 + ["test2"]*3 + ["test3"]*3
df["test_pass"] = [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]

part    test    test_pass
0   1   test1   1
1   2   test1   1
2   3   test1   0
3   1   test2   1
4   2   test2   1
5   3   test2   1
6   1   test3   1
7   2   test3   1
8   3   test3   1
```

You want the following logic (almost what you got, but using indexes):

```
df2 = df.set_index("part")
df2["part_pass"] = df.groupby("part")["test_pass"].prod()
df2 = df2.reset_index()


part    test    test_pass   part_pass
0   1   test1   1           1
1   2   test1   1           1
2   3   test1   0           0
3   1   test2   1           1
4   2   test2   1           1
5   3   test2   1           0
6   1   test3   1           1
7   2   test3   1           1
8   3   test3   1           0
```